# How to avoid http2 connect from crashing Node.js

Tags: node.js, http2

```
  const client = http2.
    connect('https://domain.doesnt.exist').
    on('error', e => {
      console.error(e.message);
    });
```

On Node.js 13.6.0, even when provided an error listener, the above code would crash the entire process.

How will I be able to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `uncaughtException` event to log all exceptions not been caught..

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log(err.message);
  console.log(err.stack);
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: I can, but it also would catch other exceptions. I only want to ignore exceptions from http2.connect.